# Django import export has error "Tablib has no format 'None' or it is not registered"

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am trying to implement csv import in my application and I have this error,
`Tablib has no format 'None' or it is not registered.`

I am using python 3.5 and Django 2.2.
I tried the same code with python 2.7 with Django 1.8 and it worked well. Is there any problem with my code?

My model:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    receive_quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    receive_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    issue_quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    issue_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    issue_to = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reorder_level = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Resources.py

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Stock, Person

class StockResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
```

Views.py:

```
from .resources import StockResource


def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stock_resource = StockResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_stock = request.FILES['myfile']

        imported_data = dataset.load(new_stock.read())
        result = stock_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test data import

        if not result.has_errors():
            stock_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Run import

    return render(request, 'csv_import.html')
```

csv_import.html

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="file" name="myfile"><br><br>
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

csv_import.csv

```
1,phone,1,0,9,0,9,9,9,,ssaine,0,2020-06-11,
2,computer,2,0,9,0,9,9,9,9,ssaine,0,2020-08-11,
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to [try](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#importing-data):

```py
imported_data = Dataset().load(new_stock.read().decode(), format='csv', headers=False)
print(imported_data)
```

If that doesn't work, verify exactly what is being returned from `new_stock.read()`.  Is it valid csv data?  You can test this out locally before you test on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error is now gone but the data is not being saved to the database. I guess there is something wrong with the CSV file. I am now trying to limit the fields and do another test.

Comment: How do I test if it is a valid CSV data?

Comment: If the creation of the Dataset is ok then it should be fine.  Just add `print(imported_data)` and if it renders formatted data then it is valid

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62465085/39296) may help you debug why the data doesn't get imported (make sure attributes and columns are set correctly, ensure fields are defined)

Answer (score 1):

for those that have headers, leave the headers option out and let django pick the headers itself, also it solves the issue of not saving to the database simplyvic raised. so use

`imported_data = Dataset().load(new_stock.read().decode(), format='csv')`

Answer (score 0):

Dont't forget to install django-import-export module and include app "import-export" in settings, installed apps.

Comment: if author has not installed django-import-export or not added in settings, the error will be totally different