# Django import-export - letting users import data

Tags: python, html, django, xlsx, django-import-export

I am trying to use django import-export to let users import their own data. I've integrated it with the admin, and that works well, but I'm having trouble getting the user import side to work.

Here are my views:

```
from .models import WordResource
from tablib import Dataset
from .models import Word
from django.contrib import messages

# Word import
def import_words(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_format = request.POST['file-format']
        word_resource = WordResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_words = request.FILES['importData']

        if file_format == 'CSV':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_words.read().decode('utf-8'),format='csv')
            result = word_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
        elif file_format == 'XLSX':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_words.read(),format='xlsx')
            result = word_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)

        if result.has_errors():
            messages.error(request, 'Uh oh! Something went wrong...')

        else:
            # Import now
            word_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
            messages.success(request, 'Your words were successfully imported')


    return render(request, 'vocab/import.html')
```

My WordResource:

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget

class WordResource(resources.ModelResource):
    target_word = Field(attribute='target_word', column_name='Russian')
    source_word = Field(attribute='source_word', column_name='Meaning')
    example_sentence = Field(attribute='example_sentence', column_name='Example sentence')
    fluency = Field(attribute='fluency', column_name='Fluency level')
    deck_name = Field(attribute='deck_name', column_name='Deck name')
    username = Field(attribute='username', column_name='username',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(User, 'username'))


    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ("username", "target_word",'source_word','example_sentence',
        'fluency', 'deck_name',)
        import_order = fields
        skip_unchanged = True
        # exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ['username']
```

My Word model:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    target_word = models.CharField('Word in Russian',max_length=25,help_text="The word you want to add, in Russian")
    source_word = models.CharField('What does it mean?',max_length=25, help_text="Write down the translation in any language")
    add_to_word_list = models.BooleanField('Would you like to create a flashcard?', default=True)
    deck_name = models.CharField('Deck name', max_length=25)
    example_sentence = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,help_text="It's important to learn words in context!")

    ## how well you know the word
    class Fluency(models.IntegerChoices):
        Beginner = 0
        Lower_intermediate = 1
        Upper_intermediate = 2
        Advanced = 3
    fluency = models.IntegerField(choices=Fluency.choices, help_text="How well do you know this word?",null=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="words",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.target_word

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("vocab:detail",
        kwargs={"username": self.user.username, "pk": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["target_word"]

        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user','target_word', 'source_word'],name='unique_word')]
```

And my import.html template:

```
{% extends "vocab/vocab_base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block content %}

{% if messages %}
<div class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
   <h3  {% if message.tags %} class=" {{ message.tags }} " {% endif %}> {{ message }} </h3>
   {% endfor %}
</div>

{% else %}

<h1> Import your words</h1>
<p>Here you can import your words from a csv or excel file.</p>

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="file" name="importData">
      <p>Please select the format of your file</p>
      <select name="file-format" class="form-control my-3">
          <option selected>Choose format...</option>
          <option>CSV</option>
          <option>XLSX</option>
        </select>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Import</button>
    </form>
  <a href="{% url 'vocab:index' %}">Back</a>
{% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
```

Strangely, it seemed to work initially when I tried with a csv file, but not with an xlsx file. I then made changes just to the xlsx part of my code. Not only did it not fix the problem, now csv doesn't work either.

Note - it's not due to the id column, as I do have a blank id column in my test upload files.

**Update** - I realised that I was missing the user field, which is a foreign (not null) key on my Word model. So I added a ForeignKeyWidget, but I'm getting the following error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: vocab_word.user_id`. The error persists even if I add a column with the user id. How can I fix this?

My csv file looks like this:

```
username;Russian;Meaning;Example Sentence;Fluency level;Deck name
testuser;word1;word2;one two three;1;new
```

Traceback after implementing Matthew's changes:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/vocab/import/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'rest_framework',
 'bootstrap4',
 'bootstrapform',
 'languages',
 'django_countries',
 'import_export',
 'django_tables2',
 'django_filters',
 'accounts',
 'vocab',
 'flash',
 'api',
 'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: vocab_word.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Russki\mysite\vocab\views.py", line 115, in import_words
    result = word_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 627, in import_data
    return self.import_data_inner(dataset, dry_run, raise_errors, using_transactions, collect_failed_rows, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 673, in import_data_inner
    raise row_result.errors[-1].error
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 569, in import_row
    self.save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 352, in save_instance
    instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /vocab/import/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: vocab_word.user_id
```

Comment: during dev, you can call with `import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)` to have exceptions bubble up to the calling process.

Comment: Also, you can print or log `imported_data` to see what the dataset looks like before running import.  You could get csv imports working 'locally' in a separate script before integrating with the web app.  This shortens the feedback loop and help you understand any data issues.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Thanks. I'm now getting a `NOT NULL constraint failed: vocab_word.user_id` and it persists even if I add a column with the user id, and after adding a ForeignKeyWidget... do you know how to fix it?

Comment: check you are referencing the correct field in the csv.  Check that it maps to the attribute on your model.  Check that the csv field maps to the correct field in the FK relation (i.e. what field do you lookup the FK.  For example: `userid = fields.Field(column_name='user_id', attribute='user', widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(User)`.  Check the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app), and if you can set breakpoints and step through you should be able to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Feel free to continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216196/django-import-export)

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Thank you, I looked at the docs again and adjusted my code, but I get the same error. I've updated my question, including my `Word` model. Could you please take another look (also, I requested access to the chat room)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is quite clear - the object cannot be created because the `user_id` field is null at the time of creation:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: vocab_word.user_id
```

Your csv contains:

```
username;Russian;Meaning;Example Sentence;Fluency level;Deck name
testuser;word1;word2;one two three;1;new
```

Your `Word` model also defines a User field:

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="words",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This means that when you declare a `Resource` in django-import-export, you need to specify how the csv `username` can be mapped to any existing `user` instances via the FK relationship.

You should use `ForeignKeyWidget` for this, because that handles mapping csv fields to objects.

- `column_name` defines the csv column we use to lookup user references
- `attribute` defines the attribute on the `Word` model that is to be set

Also, we need to ensure that User relations are looked for using the "correct" field.  From the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):

> The lookup field defaults to using the primary key (pk) as lookup criterion but can be customised to use any field on the related model.

Putting it all together, our `Field` definition looks like this:

```py
userid = fields.Field(column_name='username', attribute='user', widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(User, "username")
```

So I think the source of your error was that you were incorrectly setting `attribute` to `username`. If you debugged the code, you would probably find that the 'testuser' `User` instance had been loaded, and assigned to `Word.username`, which will just be ignored, and `Word.user` will be null, hence the error.

**Update**

Another issue to correct:

The `fields` declaration should reference the model attributes which are to be set from csv data.

Therefore the `username` field should `user`, because this is the model attribute to be updated.

```py
fields = ("user", "target_word",'source_word','example_sentence', 'fluency', 'deck_name',)
```

Comment: I still get the same error :(  I will post the Traceback in my question.

Comment: Feel free to join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216196/django-import-export)

Comment: I can't type in that room. <https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216255/room-for-matthew-hegarty-and-mel>